# FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler - NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I can't seem to call the `FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler`without it throwing an exception.

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'`

this used to work without any problem. But then I deleted the "User" objects in my parse table. Now whenever I try to login, the new user gets created in the parse table and I get the log message that the user is logged in. but when I want to call the FBRequestConnection function to retrieve the facebook id of the user I get the error.

```
- (id) init {
   if (self == [super init]) {
    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
    sharedHelper = self;
   }
   return self;
}

- (void) authenticateUserWithFacebook {
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"user_relationships",@"user_friends",@"read_friendlists"];

[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {

    if (!user) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
            [[PFFacebookUtils session] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            [[PFFacebookUtils session] close];
            [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            [[FBSession activeSession] close];
            [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
            [PFUser logOut];
        }
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
        UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

        [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:kFbIdKey];
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
        }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
        UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

        [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:kFbIdKey];
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
        }];
    }
   }];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved the issue using `[FBSession renewSystemCredentials:]` 
and also removing and reinstalling the app. I think the fact that I also deleted `Installation`objects also was related to the issue.